# Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741676 (0xC0000094)

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

When trying to launch Emulator from AVD Manager. Getting this error:

Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741676 (0xC0000094)

Already tried:

1. Added fresh emulator
2. Device Wipe out
3. Cold Start
4. Increase / Decrease RAM allowcation
5. Change Resolution (Low and High)

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it may be an issue with the Visual C++ runtime. If it is not installed please install **Visual C++** and check.

Please find the link below to download latest Visual C++.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads